# WordPress multiple menu not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

I am trying to create multiple menu in WordPress. Actually menu created and I assigned them location and saved but the problem when I call footer menu and save its just show footer menu links in both header and footer section here is my Code please help me out where I am wrong thanks. I am using WordPress 4.1

Code: Header.php

```
<nav class="site-nav">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary'
                    );
                ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( 'args' );?>
            </nav>
```

code: Footer.php

```
<nav class="site-nav">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer'
        );
        ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( 'args' );?>
</nav>
```

code: functions.php

```
function register_my_menu() {
register_nav_menus( array(
    'header' => 'Header menu',
    'footer' => 'Footer menu') );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Here is image:

First Header Menu[image]

Footer menu [image]

Location[image]

result[image]

Where I am Wrong

Answer (score 3):

**In functions.php**

```
// Register Navigation Menus
function register_my_menu() {
    $locations = array(
        'header' => 'Header Menu',
        'footer' => 'Footer Menu',
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

**In header.php**

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header') );
```

**In footer.php**

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer') );
```

Make sure to check again via Menus > Manage Locations, and have at least one item on each menu.

Comment: Thanks man its working fine but can you explain that what was there problem ? so it will be good benefit for me

Comment: @Hassan At the time of writing I wasn't sure, so I basically rewrote it from a normal approach.  Now after looking at it closer, I think it's mainly wrong on this part `wp_nav_menu( 'args' );` which it should be `wp_nav_menu( $args );`

Comment: @Hassan so will you accept the answer if there is no further questions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be the solution or not. But try renaming the args to footer_args for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your other menu is called `header` rather than `primary`. You probably just need to change the code in `Header.php` from

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
);
```

to

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'header'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display menu without theme location by pass menu name in `wp_nav_menu` function.

for **Header Menu**,

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Header Menu' ));
```

for **Footer Menu**

```
 wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Footer Menu' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'args' );?>
```

instead of the variable $args:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args );?>
```